# Non-degenerate bi-linear form

Tags: linear-algebra

By definition, a bi-linear form $H$ on a vector space $V$ is non-degenerate if that $H(u,w)=0$ for all $w\in V$ implies $u=\mathbf 0$. And I was told that in this case, one can always find a vector $x$ in $V$ such that $H(x,x)\not=0$. But I don't see any implication from non-degeneracy. I'd like to ask a favor of someone to help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Is $H$ supposed to be symmetric ?

Comment: $H(x,y)=x_1 y_2-x_2 y_1$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form on $\mathbb R^2$ satisfying $H(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $H$ is symmetric.

Then for all $y,z \in V$, you have the identity
$$H(y,z) = \frac{1}{4}\left(H(y+z,y+z)-H(y-z,y-z) \right)$$

So if $H(x,x)=0$ for all $x \in V$, then $H(y,z)=0$ for all $y,z \in V$. This is much stronger, but this implies that $H$ is degenerate.